# How do I observe a specific AJAX call by URL in JavaScript / Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a loading button component in my Ember.js application. The button should automatically get disabled when it detects that a specific XHR is made and re-enable itself when the XHR is complete. Basically, I want it to track a specific URL that I submit and change state based on that. This is what my Handlebars file currently looks like with the component:

```
{{loading-button trackMethod="POST" trackURL="/addItem" value="Add Item"}}
```

I tried accomplishing this using jQuery's `.ajaxComplete()` method in my Ember application controller but I can't get the `{{loading-button}}' component to observe any property in the application controller.

```
init: function() {
    let self = this;
    // Observe all XHRs
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        self.set('ajaxCompleteUrl', settings.url);
    });
}
```

Appreciate any pointers on how I can achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing this you could pass `isLoading` (a flag) to the component to display loading, and that property would be set on the controller that is making that request

Comment: We were doing that up until this point but now we use the button component in so many places that it's hard to keep track of states in each place. We don't want to manually set the state. Using an `isLoading` would tie in the component with the controller very tightly.

Comment: So make that button as a component and link it to service that will make the ajax.

Comment: @Keo Yes but I still have to manually set the loading state based on the response of the service. I want the component to automatically set its state based on the AJAX request by observing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ember component philosophy is **[DATA DOWN ACTIONS UP](https://github.com/DockYard/reefpoints/blob/master/source/posts/2015-10-14-best-practices-data-down-actions-up.md)**.

My scenario is similar with yours. I created a separate search button component, if the ajax is calling then set button text is 'Searching' and disable it, when ajax completed set button text is 'Search' and enable it.

search-button.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  classNames: ['col-sm-1', 'pull-right'],

  onHit: null,
  isSearching: false,
  canNotSearch: false,

  actions: {
    hit() {
      this.get('onHit')();
    }
  }
});
```

search-button.hbs

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'hit'}} disabled={{canNotSearch}}>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  {{#if isSearching}}
    {{t 'label.common.btn.searching'}}
  {{else}}
    {{t 'label.common.btn.search'}}
  {{/if}}
</button>
```

xxx-controller.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  searchObserver: Ember.observer('isSearching', function() {
    Ember.run.later( () => {
      this.set('canNotSearch', this.get('isSearching'));
    }, 100);
  }),

  actions: {

    search() {
      this.set('isSearching', true);
      Ember.run.later(() => {
        // do some ajax call(must return a promise)
        this.doSearch().then(() => {
          this.set('isSearching', false);
        });
      }, 200);
    }
  }
}
```

so, you can use your `search-button` component in any template.

```
{{button-search canNotSearch=canNotSearch isSearching=isSearching onHit=(action 'search')}}
```

Comment: See my comment above. We are doing something similar right now. We wanted to move to a system that observes the XHR directly so we don't have to manually set the `isSearching` property.